# If $p$ is an odd prime show that $2^{p-1}(2^p-1) \equiv 1 + 9p(p - 1)/2\pmod {81}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $p$ is an odd prime show that $2^{p-1}(2^p-1) \equiv 1 + 9p(p - 1)/2\pmod {81}$.

This is an exercise from Elementary Number Theory, 2nd Edition by Underwood Dudley.

I know that the expression on the LHS is an even perfect number. Furthermore, I have figured that $2^{p-1}(2^p-1) \equiv 1\pmod p$ and $2^{p-1}(2^p-1) \equiv 1\pmod 9$ for $p > 3$ but that is about it. I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with $p$ being a prime. It is true for all positive odd integers. Putting $p=18n+2k+1$ (with $0\le k<9$) it is easy to see that $1+9p(p-1)/2\bmod 81$ depends only on $k$, so for $k=0,1,2,\dots,8$ we find it is $1,28,10,28,1,10,55,55,10$.

We also find $2^{54}=1\bmod 81$. So here we apparently get a cycle three times as long, but if we calculate $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ for $p=54n+2k+1$ (with $0\le k<27$) we find it is $1,28,10,28,1,10,55,55,10$ repeated three times.

So the equality holds for all odd $p$.

Answer (score 5):

Alternately, note that whenever $p$ is odd,
$$2^{p-1}(2^{p}-1)\ =\ \frac{1}{2}((1+3)^p + (1-3)^p)\ \equiv\ 1+9p(p-1)/2 \pmod{81}.$$